# creating a database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

the below code doesn't work and when I point the curser on the first line a message says "create" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF';'
Can someone help please! thank you!

```
create table users (
id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
role_id int(11) unsigned,
phone varchar(14),
national_id int(10) not null unique,
email varchar(128) unique,
first_name varchar(32) not null,
sconed name varchar(32) not null,
third_name varchar(32) not null,
last_name varchar(32) not null,
dob date not null,

constraint foreign key(role_id)
references roles(id)
```

Comment: Did you miss closing `)` ?

Comment: You're probably missing  `;` at the end of the previous statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Based on the error, your previous statement is missing `;`
- The SQL query is missing the closing `)` or you just forgot it from the paste; something like:

  ```
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1337 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Errors present in the sql statement:

```
create table users (
id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
role_id int(11) unsigned,
phone varchar(14),
national_id int(10) not null unique,
email varchar(128) unique,
first_name varchar(32) not null,
```

> sconed name varchar(32) not null,

```
 second_name varchar(32) not null,     
 third_name varchar(32) not null,

last_name varchar(32) not null,
dob date not null,

constraint foreign key(role_id)
references roles(id)
```

> )

Answer (score 0):

```
create table users (
id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
role_id int(11),
phone varchar(14),
national_id int(10) not null unique,
email varchar(128) unique,
first_name varchar(32) not null,
sconed_name varchar(32) not null,
third_name varchar(32) not null,
last_name varchar(32) not null,
dob date not null,

constraint foreign key(role_id)
references roles(id));
```